# Exception reading manifest from file. Microsoft Word Add-in VSTO

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, vsto, libgit2sharp

I am trying to create a Microsoft Word add-in that will add and commit to a git repo every time the Word document is saved, either auto save or manual save. I have been able to get the functionality I desire when I run the program from within Visual Studio (debug mode). When I publish and install the add-in so that it runs when Word starts, I get the following error.

[image]

Now when I try to add the LibGit2Sharp NuGet packages, running in debug mode from within Visual Studio gives me this error:

[image]

and the following error details:

```
Name: 
From: file:///C:/Users/short/OneDrive for Business/SCHOOL/JP/EZGit/EZGit/MicrosoftWordAddIn/bin/Debug/MicrosoftWordAddIn.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Users/short/OneDrive%20for%20Business/SCHOOL/JP/EZGit/EZGit/MicrosoftWordAddIn/bin/Debug/MicrosoftWordAddIn.dll.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. ---> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Application manifest is not semantically valid. ---> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: File element lib\fedora-x64\native\..\libgit2-106a5f2.so must have a relative path.
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateFile(File f)
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSemanticsForApplicationRole()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSemanticsForApplicationRole()
   at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

I think the published solution needs the packages, but works from within Visual Studio without them. I installed them to see and then running from within Visual Studio causes an error.

I have tried changing the .csproj file to add the following

```
<Target Name="EnsureNetstandardFilesAreIncludedInClickOnce" BeforeTargets="_DeploymentComputeClickOnceManifestInfo">
    <Message Text="Adding netstandard files to ClickOnce" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <PublishFile Include="@(_NETStandardLibraryNETFrameworkLib->'%(FileName)')" KeepMetadata="None">
        <PublishState>Include</PublishState>
        <FileType>Assembly</FileType>
      </PublishFile>
    </ItemGroup>
    <!-- Consider using ReferenceCopyLocalPaths instead, if we are missing files -->
    <Message Text="Adding nuget files to ClickOnce" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <PublishFile Include="@(ReferencePath->'%(FileName)')" Condition=" '%(ReferencePath.NuGetSourceType)' == 'Package' and '%(ReferencePath.NuGetIsFrameworkReference)' != 'true'" KeepMetadata="None">
        <PublishState>Include</PublishState>
        <FileType>Assembly</FileType>
      </PublishFile>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Adding Private True references to ClickOnce" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <PublishFile Include="@(ReferencePath->'%(FileName)')" Condition="'%(ReferencePath.Private)' == 'True'" KeepMetadata="None">
        <PublishState>Include</PublishState>
        <FileType>Assembly</FileType>
      </PublishFile>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Comment: According to site rules, all relevant information such as code and error messages need to be plain text, within the question itself. Please do not provide these things as pictures. Pictures are often difficult to read and the content cannot be copy/pasted for testing or research purposes.

Comment: With the picture, I couldn't get the error any other way, and it didn't allow me to copy and paste. The second error is my bad, I thought since there was a super long line, putting it in a code box would be easier to read.

Comment: I've incorporated the clarification and the pictures into the question. The observation about error information in pictures stands: that first one is not readable. And people who could help you are more likely to do so if they could copy/paste the readable error message so that it can be researched. You're asking professionals to use their own time to assist you - it's in your own interest to take the time to write the information out...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not familiar with the correct ways of posting on here.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue as well and resolved it by removing the import statement in the csproj file at the top. The lib2git library is still referenced in the ItemGroup section