# MS WORD VSTO Add-in: Exception reading manifest from file

Tags: c#, vsto, word-addins

I'm getting the following error during a loading of a [Microsoft WORD VSTO Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/create-vsto-add-ins-for-office-by-using-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) that I created using `VS2019` on `Windows 10 Pro`. The adding was loading fine before. Question: What could have been the cause of the error and how can the issue be resolved? Found some similar issues online (like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59959944/1232087)) but still no luck.

**Error**:

```
Name:
From: file:///C:/DotNet2019/VSTO/MyWORDAddinProj/bin/Debug/MyWORDAddinProj.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/DotNet2019/VSTO/MyWORDAddinProj/bin/Debug/MyWORDAddinProj.dll.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. ---> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed: 
            -HRESULT:   0x80070c81
             Start line:    0
             Start column:  0
             Host file:      ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070C81
   at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateCMSFromXml(Byte[] buffer, UInt32 bufferSize, IManifestParseErrorCallback Callback, Guid& riid)
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(FileStream fileStream)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

**Event Viewer shows more detailed info. Along with the above error, it shows the following**:

```
************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4180.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60828.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4180.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4001.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60828.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60828.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60828.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4150.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Deployment
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Deployment/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Deployment.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Security
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Security/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Security.dll
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest enabling logging and then take a look at logs generated, see [Enhanced Logging in ClickOnce Deployment](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/enhanced-logging-in-clickonce-deployment/) for more information.

There are too many cases for such exceptions... First of all, make sure that you did all the steps described in the [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2019) article. But the log can tell you more. Also, you may find the [Troubleshoot Office solution deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/troubleshooting-office-solution-deployment?view=vs-2019) page helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game but I got this error at least two times. In my case it was triggered by two things coming together but it might be something different for your case.

- You are building a VSTO project (customization or AddIn) in the new SDK-style of the .csproj
- You are using the nuget package System.ComponentModel.Annotation directly or via another dependency. In my case that was via the nuget package Polly.Core.

I do not know if the target Office application (Word, Outlook, Excel) makes a difference.

If you are looking to the build output you might see a line like the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(303,9): warning MSB3112: Two or more assemblies have the same identity 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A, ProcessorArchitecture=msil'.
```

If you look at a diagnostic build you see that the DLL System.ComponentModel.Annotation is referenced two times as input for the build step that produces an application manifest (GenerateApplicationManifest).
The build seems to include the DLLs from the lib-folder and the ref-folder of the package. If you download and extract the package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Annotations you will see two DLLs.

This is only a warning but ultimately lead to the error.

I could overcome this by doing one of the three things pointed out:

- Getting rid of direct package references to System.ComponentModel.Annotations by replacing it with the direct dependency to the old .NET-Framework variant System.ComponentMode.DataAnnotations (watch out for the "Data" in the name) like so:

  ```
  <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
  ```
- If a newer version is needed (I guess there are new attributes defined in the package) or this is a transient dependency via for example Polly.Core there is a trick to talk the build process into not referencing all files (from the ref-folder of a package) but still copying the relevant files. You might need some additional things. If you get a FileNotFoundException during the execution of the vsto or a Unit test.

  ```
   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Polly.Core" Version="8.3.0" IncludeAssets="compile" GeneratePathProperty="true"  />
     <Content Include="$(PkgPolly_Core)\lib\net462\Polly.Core.dll" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />

     <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.0" IncludeAssets="compile" GeneratePathProperty="true"  />
     <Content Include="$(PkgSystem_ComponentModel_Annotations)\lib\net461\*.*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />

     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" Version="8.0.0" IncludeAssets="compile" GeneratePathProperty="true"  />
     <Content Include="$(PkgMicrosoft_Bcl_AsyncInterfaces)\lib\net462\*.*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />

     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.Timeprovider" Version="8.0.1" IncludeAssets="compile" GeneratePathProperty="true"  />
     <Content Include="$(PkgMicrosoft_Bcl_Timeprovider)\lib\net462\*.*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
   </ItemGroup>
  ```
- Making a unit test that tries to load the generated VSTO with the DLLs that are also used by System.Deployment in the loading stage of the VSTO file. This way you can see if the error reappears later. Here is a helper class for that:

  ```
   public static class VstoManifestVerifier
   {
     public static void VerifyVstoManifestIsReadable(string manifestPath)
     {
       if (File.Exists(manifestPath) == false)
         Assert.Fail($"Manifest file '{manifestPath}' does not exist.");

       // NOTE: magic number from System.Deployment assembly that calls the native method too
       var guid = Guid.Parse("a504e5b0-8ccf-4cb4-9902-c9d1b9abd033");
       var manifestParseErrorCallback = new ManifestParseErrorCallback();

       var manifest = IsolationInterop.ParseManifest(manifestPath, manifestParseErrorCallback, ref guid);

       Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(manifest);
       Assert.That(manifestParseErrorCallback.Error, Is.Null, () => $"Error in '{manifestPath}' Manifest would not be able to load in Office.");
     }

     private static class IsolationInterop
     {
       [DllImport("mscorwks.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
       [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
       internal static extern object ParseManifest(
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr), In] string pszManifestPath,
         [In] IManifestParseErrorCallback pIManifestParseErrorCallback,
         [In] ref Guid riid);
     }

     [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
     [Guid("ace1b703-1aac-4956-ab87-90cac8b93ce6")]
     [ComImport]
     private interface IManifestParseErrorCallback
     {
       void OnError(
         [In] uint StartLine,
         [In] uint nStartColumn,
         [In] uint cCharacterCount,
         [In] int hr,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr), In] string ErrorStatusHostFile,
         [In] uint ParameterCount,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] string[] Parameters);
     }

     private class ManifestParseErrorCallback : IManifestParseErrorCallback
     {
       public string Error { get; private set; }

       public ManifestParseErrorCallback()
       {
       }

       public void OnError(
           [In] uint StartLine,
           [In] uint nStartColumn,
           [In] uint cCharacterCount,
           [In] int hr,
           [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string ErrorStatusHostFile,
           [In] uint ParameterCount,
           [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] string[] Parameters)
       {
         Error += $"StartLine: {StartLine}, nStartColumn: {nStartColumn}, cCharacterCount: {cCharacterCount}, hr: {hr}, ErrorStatusHostFile: {ErrorStatusHostFile}, ParameterCount: {ParameterCount} Parameters: {Parameters}";
       }
     }
   }
  ```

There are two things that I can think of to overcome the error in a different fashion if you cannot remove the dependency. I lack sufficient msbuild-skills to do that but I have seen other people overcome build problems in a similiar fashion. See the magic that someone came up with here: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1630#issuecomment-363199457

- Overriding the package reference with the .NET Framework reference. Though I clearly do not know how to do that and if that would work. But it should be possible to remove the DLLs of System.ComponentMode.Annotations somewhere doing the build steps and replacing it with System.ComponentMode.DataAnnotations
- Removing the erroneous System.ComponentMode.DataAnnotations from the ref-folder right before the build step that generates the assembly manifest (GenerateApplicationManifest) from the respective input of the build step.